# How do I configure spring-data-mongodb to use multiple mongos instances for HA?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

XML config 'mongo:mongo' has 'host/port' or 'replica-set' attributes. Can I use 'replicaSet' with multiple mongos instances?